# Expected value for independent set in graph

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, graph-theory

> Prove that the every simple graph G(V,E) has an independent set with at least $\sum_{v\in{V}} \left(\frac{1}{\left(\text{deg}(v)+1\right)}\right)$.
>
> Hint : you can find the expected value of it

My idea is simple. We can find an independent set like this . We choose randomly a vertex v . We put it in the independent set ( let's call it : A , we are going to calculate $E(|A|)$) . Since v , it's in the independent set, there is no need to examine it's neighbors, so we "delete" them .
Let's examine it , from a probabilistic perspective . For every set of ( deg(v) + 1) vertices, a vertex in this set has the chance to included in A , with propability $p(v) =$ $\frac{1}{1+\operatorname{deg}(v)}$ .
So the $E(|A|)$ = $\sum_{v\in{V}}Ap(v)$ where A takes values in $[1,n]$. So $E(|A|)=\frac{\sum_{v\in{V}}A}{\sum_{v\in{V}} \operatorname{deg}(v) +1}= ?$ I am pretty sure that ${\sum_{v\in{V}}A}\ne 1$.  Any hint in what I am missing?
update : i think that the purpose of the hint is to use the propabilistic method ( of Paul Erdos)

Comment: You talk about probabilities, but you haven't specified a distribution.

Comment: it's for a discrete mathematics course assigment , my professor did not mention something about propability in the paper, and I don't find it that strange because we discuss  about a graph . There are many many graphs that belong to the description simple non directed graph and there is not another clue in the exercise to imply that the degree of it's vertices follows a distirbution

Comment: That seems to be a misunderstanding. I wasn't talking about a distribution of the degrees. You write that "a vertex in this set has the chance to be included in $A$ with probability ...". You (not necessarily your professor) must have some distribution in mind when you say that; otherwise there would be no probabilities. You didn't tell us which distribution you assumed to arrive at this probability. At one point, you write "we choose randomly a vertex $v$", but you don't say with which distribution (perhaps you meant a uniform distribution?), and you don't say how further vertices are chosen.

Comment: I don't know a lot about probabilistic graph theory, so I don't personally find that hint very helpful. A small modification to your algorithm will work, however, to find an independent set of the desired size; you may then prove the bound by induction on order. A hint for the modification: don't pick vertices at random; choose them by some criterion by which you think you could grow a large independent set (further hint: just look at the bound you're trying to prove).

Comment: As another remark, your algorithm of choosing a vertex at random and deleting it along with all its neighbors gives rise to the (much worse in general) bound of $\alpha(G) \geq \frac{n}{\Delta(G) + 1}$ (in a graph of order $n$).

Comment: @Paralyzed_by_Time i think i agree with you , i calculated that but it is not what this exercise states, that's why i asked here